# Animation Drawing in MFC

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mfc

One parent window have some child window for animation.
Each child window have thread, Its thread calculate next animation location and then, call the invalidate method.
So, each child window receive WM_PAINT message, and then paint.
When parent window have many child window for animation, WM_PAINT message was too many occurred.
Although I have been painting using D2D library, Performance is not satisfaction.
Please advise me

Comment: How many is many ?

Comment: approximately above 10 child windows.
whenever added, every child windows animation performance are down.

Comment: [DirectComposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directcomp/directcomposition-portal).

Comment: Thank you for your help, DirectComposition is very nice.

Comment: @IInspectable You can make an answer instead of the comment.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information in the question to warrant an answer. Availability of a [mcve] would change the odds of someone posting an answer.